# Java Converting from String to Enum

Tags: java, string

I'm pretty new to Java and am not sure how to approach this problem. I have a string which can contain Enums but in String version.
For example:

```
String str = "Hello Color.RED what's up?"
```

how do I convert Color.RED to an enum in the string above?

Comment: You mean to the enum's value?

Comment: Do you want it to say `Hello Color.RED` or just `Hello RED`? Also is `Color` a personal enum, or does it come from `java.awt`?

Comment: I kind of want it to generate a new string which should be something like this
"Hello" + Color.RED + "what's up"

Comment: To clarify a previous comment, Is Color your enum?  Because  `java.awt.Color` is a class not an enum.

Comment: @WJS no Color is just an example, my actual Enum is ChatColor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find the text `RED`, e.g. using a *regex*, then you call `Color.valueOf(name)`.

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bColor\\.([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    String name = m.group(1);
    Color color = Color.valueOf(name);
    System.out.println(color);
}
```

Comment: not what I was expecting but works well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, is to use `String.replaceAll` to isolate the color within the string. This removes everything `except` the color.  The `\\S+` says one or more non space characters.  So it could be anything, including something like `@#I@S`.  You could modify that to fit the constraints of your enum.

```
String str = "Hello Color.RED what's up?";
    
String colr = str.replaceAll(".*\\bColor\\.(\\S+).*", "$1");
Color color = Color.valueOf(colr);
System.out.println(color);
```